# Constrained Hamiltonian problems

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, constrained-dynamics, classical-field-theory, poisson-brackets

What happens to the poisson bracket structure of Hamiltonian phase space if We have some constraints in $p$ and $q$. What physical aspects this structure represents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite broad question. Briefly speaking, starting from the non-degenerate canonical [Poisson bracket structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket), according to the Dirac-Bergmann analysis, the constraints can in principle (assuming various regularity conditions) be classified into [first and second class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint). The physical relevant (possibly degenerate) Poisson structure is the [Dirac bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket), made with the help of the second class constraints.

Comment: Is there any other fundamental problem other than ones posed by the existence of secondl class constraints